# free software for debugging shaders

Tags: debugging, glsl

Are there any free software tools to debug GLSL shaders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [glslDevil](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/)

Answer (score 2):

*Just adding this answer for future readers:*

On OS X, if you have the Developer Tools installed (a free download for the most current OS version), one of the many tools aside from Xcode is the [OpenGL Shader Builder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLShaderBuilderUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006476-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5) which :

> [...] is a tool for developing and **debugging** programs for the graphics processing unit (GPU).  It can help you visualize and preview shader objects without the complexity of surrounding code.
>   [...] You can use the shader builder with **programs written with OpenGL Shading Language** or with older-style ARB vertex and fragment programs.  OpenGL Shader Builder also supports geometry shaders, a recent addition to the OpenGL specification.

*Emphasis added*